# Laravel 5 redirect()->back() doesn't work as expected

Tags: php, redirect, url-routing, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I've got a problem with `redirect()->back()` when there is no `HTTP_REFERER` set.

Normally when I open my URL with an ID as parameter to show a specific datarow:
`http://my-domain/module/ID`

If the specified `ID` is not existent or the current loggedin user has no permission to open it, I make

```
if (!$this->checkPermission($id)) {
    return redirect()->back()->withError('message');
}
// do my stuff to show the datarow
```

But when I change the browsers address field and load an non-permitted `ID` then there is no `HTTP_REFERER` set and `redirect()->back()` redirects me to my last loaded JavaScript `for_this_view.js` (and shows it) added in the view as following:

**app.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
    @section('head')
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    {!! HTML::style('assets/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.css?ver=1.11.4') !!}
    <!-- some more scripts -->
    @show
</head>

<body>
    @yield('content')
</body>
</html>
```

**show.blade.php**

```
@extends('app')

@section('head')
    @parent
    {!! HTML::script('for_this_view.js') !!}
@stop

@section('content')
    <!-- display datarow -->
@stop
```

What is `redirect()->back()` doing here?
If there is no URL to redirect back laravel is guessing one? And why? Maybe to ever have a way to redirect.

That make me not able to use this function.

**UPDATE**

Ah, maybe I found my problem...

I've tried to dynamically load JavaScript's if they exist in a specific folder.
I do that, because I want my JavaScript's be parsed like a view to get Blade Syntax in it. I added a specific folder to the `/config/view.php` and made files like `for_this_view_js.blade.php`. They are dynamically added as `for_this_view.js` in the `routes.php`.

And therefore I made something like:

```
/* load view javascripts */
/** @var \SplFileInfo $path */
foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
        new RecursiveDirectoryIterator(public_path())
    ) as $path)
{
    if ($path->isFile()
        && ends_with($path->getFilename(), 'js.blade.php'))
    {
        Route::get('url_to_javascript.js', function() {
            $contents = View::make('for_this_view_js(.blade.php)');
            $response = Response::make($contents);
            $response->header('Content-Type', 'application/javascript');
            return $response;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Call `Session::previousUrl()` what does it return?

Comment: @lukasgeiter It shows the url to the JavaScript loaded directly before `for_this_view.js` but this time it was specified in `app.blade.php`...

Comment: Does this request get handled by laravel? (and not just by the webserver like javascript files are loaded usually)

Comment: OK, I forgot an important information in my question. See UPDATE section. That could be my problem. But how can I improve that code to load my JS-File with Blade and prevent the error when redirecting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If no `HTTP_REFERER` is set, Laravel tries to get the last request from the session. This URL is stored in `Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession`:

```
protected function storeCurrentUrl(Request $request, $session)
{
    if ($request->method() === 'GET' && $request->route() && ! $request->ajax())
    {
        $session->setPreviousUrl($request->fullUrl());
    }
}
```

As you can see there are a few conditions, which unfortunately your JS requests fulfill:

1. GET method
2. Handled by a route
3. Not an ajax request

### Solution

As I see it, you have two options.

#### Disable the middleware

*Warning: I haven't tested this and there could be side-effects*

Go to `app/Http/Kernel.php` and remove `'Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession',` from the `$middleware`. Now if no `HTTP_REFERER` is set, Laravel will simply redirect to the root of your application (`/`)

#### Extend the middleware and add additional constraints

You could extend the middleware and add some additional checking:

```
class CustomStartSession extends \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession {
    public function storeCurrentUrl(Request $request, $session){
        if(!ends_with($request->url(), '.js')){
            parent::storeCurrentUrl($request, $session);
        }
    }
}
```

Then enable it by replacing the original `StartSession` in `app/Http/Kernel.php` with yours and any request with an URL ending in `.js` will not be saved as "previous url"

#### Update

Apparently the middleware needs to be registered as a singleton to be fully functional. You can do that by adding this in the `register` method of one of your service providers (e.g. `AppServiceProvider`)

```
$this->app->singleton('App\Http\Middleware\CustomStartSession');
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks. Nice solution! I've just changed your `if` clause to `if (!ends_with($request->url(), '.js')) {...}`

Comment: After overwriting the StartSession the login breaks with "TokenMismatch"-Error and the logout does nothing. Hrmpf, thank you anyway...

Comment: are you sure? because just by overriding `storeCurrentUrl` you shouldn't be able to break something... If you change it back to Laravels `StartSession` everything works?

Comment: Yes, I do not understand it myself. My fix for login/logout errors was to use the original StartSession-Class.

Comment: Did your custom `StartSession` class extend the original class correctly?

Comment: Yes it does. It works also as expected, when I'm logged in. There is a file in `/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/SessionServiceProvider.php` that has following line `$this->app->singleton('Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession');`. If I change this line to `$this->app->singleton('App\Http\Middleware\CustomStartSession');` it works... But this could not be the correct solution.

Comment: Ah I see. That's probably the problem... Obviously you can't change Laravels core. Revert that and try to register your custom class in one of your ServiceProviders with `$this->app->singleton('App\Http\Middleware\CustomStartSession');`

Comment: Ok, seems to work, also with login/logout. Thank again. Will you update your answer? I'm a bit new to laravel. Now I have to understand what I've done ;)

Comment: Great! I honestly am not entirely sure why this middleware needs to be a singleton.. But I'll definitely add it to the answer.

Comment: OK, there is still a problem... In principle, everything works, but I sometimes have to click multiple times on 'Logout' (/auth/logout) to make it work. Any ideas?

Comment: Just for answering your open questions why this middleware needs to be a singleton. It needs to be a singleton because we wanna have the same session with the same content for each following request. Otherwise a new session will be initialized on every request to the application.

Answer (score 1):

My current work-around is to extend the `BaseController` like this:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesCommands;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;

abstract class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use DispatchesCommands, ValidatesRequests;

    /**
     * The fallback url for redirects...
     * Prevent faulty redirect if 'HTTP_REFERER' not set.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    private static $back_url = '';

    /**
     * @param string $back_url The fallback url for redirects...
     */
    public static function setBackUrl($back_url)
    {
        self::$back_url = $back_url;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    protected static function getBackUrl()
    {
        return self::$back_url;
    }

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public static function redirect_back()
    {
        $back = self::getBackUrl();
        if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']))
        {
            return redirect()->back();

        } else if (!empty($back)) {
            return redirect()->to($back);

        } else {
            return redirect()->to('/');
        }
    }
}
```

And then call it like this:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

/**
 * Class MyController
 *
 * @package App\Http\Controllers
 */
class MyController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Check permission for specified '$id'.
     *
     * @param int|string $id The datarow id
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function checkPermission($id)
    {...}

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @param int|string $id The datarow id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index($id)
    {
        if (!$this->checkPermission($id)) {
            self::setBackUrl(\URL::route('my_prefered_fallback_route'));
            return self::redirect_back()
                ->withErrors(["message"]);
        }

        return 'Hello, API';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is uggly but you can avoid storeCurrentUrl() by changing request method to POST in your Controller.

```
$request->setMethod('POST');
```